# Creating a parent type to multiple enumeration objects

Tags: scala, enumeration, traits

I want to create multiple Enumeration objects, all inheriting from one parent. The reason why I want them inheriting from one parent is that I want to create a collection of Enumerations from the objects and group them under that type.

```
object Searchable{
  trait SearchFlags{  
    self: Enumeration => 
      type Value = self.Value
  }
}

object SearchableByLocation{
    object SearchFlags extends Enumeration{ 
      val Flag1 = Value
    }
}

object SearchableByAge{
    object SearchFlags extends Enumeration{ 
      val Flag1 = Value
    }
}

object Test extends App{
  //I cannot refer to members of a trait directly, so the 
  //underlying type of Set is invalid
  val flags: Set[ Searchable.SearchFlags.Value ] = Set( SearchableByLocation.SearchFlags.Flag1, SearchableByAge.SearchFlags.Flag1 )
}
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know trait member types could be referred to using `#`. The following works:

```
object Searchable{
  trait SearchFlags extends Enumeration
}

object SearchableByLocation{
  object SearchFlags extends Searchable.SearchFlags{ 
    val Flag1 = Value
  }
}

object SearchableByAge{
  object SearchFlags extends Searchable.SearchFlags{ 
    val Flag1 = Value
  }
}

object Test extends App{
  val flags: Set[ Searchable.SearchFlags#Value ] = Set( SearchableByLocation.SearchFlags.Flag1, SearchableByAge.SearchFlags.Flag1 )
}
```

Comment: This is probably not what you want. By calling the same Value function on both enumerations, you are making all instances of both enums fully compatible. This would allow you to pass a SearchableByAge value to a method expecting a SearchableByLocation value. Both are of type Searchable.SearchFlags#Value. This is a cumbersome way to create a single enum ;-)

Comment: @DanielL. Thanks for your input, but I'm not sure I understood what you're trying to say. Value method in `val Flag1 = Value` returns a value of respective `Value` types . Check this out: http://sprunge.us/iTPM 
Also removed a leftover comment from my answer.

Comment: Interesting! I find it curious that you are getting instances of the same Searchable.SearchFlags#Value that are at the same time of different type, but the implementation of Enumeration is pretty convoluted, so fair if it works for you ;-)

Comment: @DanielL. I think that's what type projection operator `#` does, Types are based on projected member of individual instances. The individual instances here are SearchableByAge.SearchFlags and SearchableByLocation.SearchFlags

Answer (score 1):

Well, Scala's enumeration objects are nothing more than a series of values of a shared type. You need to create the common trait and then guarantee that the constants are of that type. This works:

```
  trait CommonBase

  object Enum1 extends Enumeration
  {
    protected class Enum1Val extends Val with CommonBase
    protected final def enum1Value() = new Enum1Val()

    val A, B, C = enum1Value()
  }

  object Enum2 extends Enumeration
  {
    protected class Enum2Val extends Val with CommonBase
    protected final def enum2Value() = new Enum2Val()

    val D, E, F = enum2Value()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val flags: Set[ CommonBase ] = Set( Enum1.A, Enum2.D )
  }
```

Of course, you do need to create your own value type and your own factory method to produce your new type instead of the default type that comes with Enumeration.